# residual correlation remains after seasonal lag added

Tags: auto-correlation

I'm attempting to model operating margins and a time plot indicated that the series may follow an autoregressive process. I initially fitted data to an AR(1) model and it appeared that residual correlation was present in the 4th lag term. I added an additional 4th lag and while the AC in the fourth residual did decrease, the t-stat is still slightly greater than 2. Additionally, the second (4th lagged regressor) appears to be highly insignificant. I'm looking for suggestions as to how to improve on the model specification.

Comment: Instead of trying to solve two problems with one model, I'd just first deseasonalize it with something like the X-11 algorithm and then feed my AR process the deseasonalized data. That would be my path of least resistance.

Answer (score 1):

what you should analyze:

- Look at seasonalities as user Horeseless points out.
- Look at ACF, if it cuts off suddenly then there is something of MA nature, if it decays slowly then it is rather AR.
- Look at partial ACF to see which lags are relevant.

You find theory and code [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/9).

Answer (score 0):

Before fitting any ARIMA model, make sure that:

1. There is no seasonal trend in your data. If it is present then deseasonalized it by taking appropriate lag difference, as pointed by @Horseless
2. Before fitting any model, make sure data is stationary.
3. Once stationarity is achieved, plot ACF and PACF and find appropriate lag. To find appropriate lag selection, you can use various information criterion, like AIC, BIC, SIC, HQIC etc. (Lot of R packages are available that allow automatic selection of appropriate lag order)

After fitting appropriate model, make sure that error terms (residuals) are white noise.

Answer (score -1):

you should look arch/garch models

Comment: errors could have GARCH variance ... but your 6 words don't help here.

Comment: Gonna need him/her to elaborate more on the question to elaborate my answer. I cant comment so I had to post as answer. Vague question calls for a vague answer. @Richard why don't you help him/her?

Comment: I don't think this answer is useful in that case. If the point of the question is not clear this does not mean that the answers do not have to try to provide something that helps...It would be appreciated to embed your comment in a broader framework such that everyone gets what you hint to